# Minimal dimension for immersions to be dense in the continuous function space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f:[0,1]^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be an arbitrary continuous function.

My question is, under what conditions for $m$, there exists an immersion $g:(-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\|f - g\|_\infty<\delta$ for any $\delta>0$?

In other words, are immersions are dense in the space $C([0,1]^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ of continuous functions?

I found that if $m\geq 2n$, there exists such $g$ in the proof of the Whitney Embedding Theorem.
(Theorem 3.17 in [this paper](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:735867/FULLTEXT01.pdf))

I guess we can relax this condition in the simple case $[0,1]^n$: such as if $m \geq n+1$, such $g$ exists.

Comment: I suspect the $m  \geq n+1$ is not true.  For example, take a map $[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb R^3$  that restricts on a disc to the cone on a non-trivial knot.   I don't see a way to uniformly approximate that by an immersion.  It's true knots in $\mathbb R^3$ bound immersed discs but I don't know a way to approximate by immersed discs.

Comment: I have a feeling that the existence of such a $g$ should depend on the codimension of the (interior) autointersections of the image of $f$ (whenever this makes sense). This would explain why for $m\ge2n$ it always exists, but for $n\le m<2n$ it depends on $f$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found an answer to my question from [1].

> Theorem 5.10. Let $f: M \rightarrow N$ be a continuous map. If $f$ is homotopic to an immersion $g: M \rightarrow N$, then $f$ can be approximated by an immersion. (Recall that $\operatorname{dim}M<\operatorname{dim} N$).

Because there exists an immersion $g:[0,1]^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ that is homotopic to any continuous function, any continuous map can be approximated by an immersion.

[1] Hirsch, Morris W. "Immersions of manifolds." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 93.2 (1959): 242-276.